# get the complement of a scope in rails / a scope that filters out matching entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, inverse

I am building a model which keeps track of posts that a given user has read (in Rails 3).  The table that tracks this is 'readings.'   a reading belongs_to both :user  and :post, both of which has_many :readings. When a user sees a post, it is marked as read, and a 'reading' is created with the user_id and post_id. This seems to work fine, but now I am trying to write a scope that returns only unread posts for a given user.  Finding read posts works fine:

```
scope :read, lambda { |user_id = nil |       
    user_id.nil? ? {} : joins(:readings).where('readings.user_id = :user_id', :user_id => user_id)
}
```

However my attempts to return the complement of this set (unread posts) are failing.  How can this be done? Is there a general way to write a scope(method) that just returns the complement of another(here, :read)? I would also be happy to write this as a class method that works the same as a scope.

Bear in mind that readings are only created when a post is read, so a new post would have no readings.  This seemed more economical than creating entries for every user for every new post.

EDIT:  OK, I am getting closer - the below scope almost works, but does not require that all readings for a post are not equal to user_id.  Thus if user #1 has read a post, and so has user #2, that other reading is queried and found to be not equal. So the post is wrongly found to be unread.

```
scope :unread, lambda { |user_id = nil |       
    user_id.nil? ? {} : includes(:readings).where('(readings.user_id IS NULL OR readings.user_id != :user_id)', :user_id => user_id)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the below works.  Still testing though.  If anyone finds a hole in here happy to re-open.

```
scope :unread_by, lambda { |user_id = nil, hide_unread = nil|
      { :joins => "LEFT JOIN readings ON  readings.post_id    = post.id
          AND readings.user_id        = #{user_id}",
          :conditions => 'readings.id IS NULL' }
}
```